# Как занести в переменную файл?

Tags: массивы, include, php

Здравствуйте. Как занести в переменную значение из файла? Пробовал сделать так:

```
$msg=include "a.html";
```

но он вывел мне сам текст. А если написать `echo $msg;` то выведет `1`. Как поступают  втаких случаях?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Инклуд возвращает результат инклуда файла**(0 - false)** или **(1 - true)**. А получать содержимое можно так:

> ```
> $msg = file_get_contents("a.html");
> ```

или так:

> ```
> $msg = file("a.html");
> ```

Но разницы почти никакой)

Comment: Разве во втором варианте $msg не будет массивом???